# How to write to Azure Mobile Services

Tags: android, android-studio, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services, android-studio-3.0

I'm new to Azure and would like to know how i can write to a SQL table in azure mobile services in a way such that when a button is clicked and data is inserted. I am currently developing a mobile app using android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Azure!

This tutorial "[Create an Android App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started)" shows you how to add a cloud-based backend service to an Android mobile app by using an Azure mobile app backend. You will create both a new mobile app backend and a simple Todo list Android app that stores app data in Azure SQL Database.